# Basic of Capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

I've 2 capacitors; plate area, difference between plates and dielectric is same. Only thing is that the metal used in plates is different. Since the formula $\displaystyle C=\frac{\varepsilon A}{d}$ states, it won't affect but why?

Answer (score 5):

The only property of metals used in deriving $C=\varepsilon A/d$ is that they are perfect conductors. Ideally, all metals have this property. So even if you change the metal, it should not matter.

But if you use something other than metal, then it will of course change the capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

All real metals have some resistivity: when you go to charge or discharge the capacitor, it takes a little bit of work for the charges to distribute themselves on the plates. Two capacitors with the same geometry but different conductors will have different resistivities.  You can model this as a small resistance $R$ in series with the capacitor, so that the capacitor will take some finite time $t\sim RC$ to discharge when shorted. For a real capacitor, $R$ is probably micro-ohms; in any real circuit, other resistances will completely dominate the charging behavior and the capacitor's conductor won't matter.